# Redirect to different subfolders according to geolocation without affecting SEO

Tags: seo, redirects, country-specific, international

I want to open different pages by default in different countries. But It affects SEO of main URL.

Like my website is `example.com`. I want to open this URL in India and `example.com/abc` outside India by default.

But my SEO of `example.com` should not be affected. how can I achieve that? I have written following script for this on top of index page.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://ipapi.co/json/',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
        if(data.country_name.toUpperCase() != "INDIA")
             window.location.href = "/abc";
        }
    });
</script>
```

It is navigating fine, but it is deindexing `example.com` from google

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rel=alternate` to indicate that the `example.com/abc` is for outside India and that `example.com` is the default version. This way a user in India will find the `example.com` in his search results and any other user will see `example.com/abc` in his search results while in another country.

[Checkout the google webmaster blog about `rel=alternate`](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html).

Answer (score -1):

I applied a different solution which is working fine now.

I created a script.js file for above redirection script and added it to my index page.  Then I disallowed this script.js file for googlebot in robots.txt

Comment: Hiding redirects from Googlebot is against the Google Webmaster Guidelines.  They call that [sneaky redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721217?hl=en).

Comment: Agreed @StephenOstermiller. I'll remove it